# Android browser code

Tags: android

how can we look at the Browser's code and see how it plays videos embedded using the  tag?
Please help

Answer (score 3):

The page for the android source code is here: http://source.android.com/source/index.html

You will need to dig into the git repository...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following links

- [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/search/?query=google+android&entity=project)
- [Android Open source project](http://android.git.kernel.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Browser](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#bgE3O5Qa1bM/src/com/android/browser/BrowserActivity.java) code tree in git.

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout from the git using 
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser.git

For other packages just use this link
https://github.com/android/